# UITableViewCell with Lazy XML Parsing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xml-parsing

I've used apple's Lazy TableImages example for loading images in the backgournd and it works fine.

My question is if this same technique can be used to parse xml responses after issuing url requests for each cell?

I've tried this based on the Lazy table image loading, it works, but it freezes unitl all the visible cells have parsed their appropriate xml. I haven't tried to create a seperate thread to process each xml for parsing, but i don't know if this is the right way.

Teo.

Answer (score 1):

Please look into [this](http://codeshape.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/creating-an-asynchronous-xml-parser-for-ios-applications/)

Hope it works.